# Is there a job queue system that allows tasks to be dependent on other tasks?

Tags: php, job-queue

For example, I'm working on a deployment app. Let's say we deploy 4 branches from SVN, that requires 4 `svn export` from subversion. This may take a while depending on the branch we check out so I was thinking of sending this to a job queue. When all jobs are complete, then and only then do we want to restart our application services.

Is there a job queue that can do this? I think the closest I've seen is celery since it takes results into a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux, you could use something like Cron to automate/schedule the start of your jobs (ex. 1 time per day) at a certain point and pipe the output of that job to a PHP script that could store the time that your job finishes in a database. You could have a second "monitoring" PHP script that would run more frequently (like once every half hour or something) that would query the database to see if all of your jobs have finished. If all of your jobs for that date were marked as "done", you could use that PHP script to kick off your restart. You don't have to write this in PHP and I'm sure it could all be written in Perl or as a shell script or something as well - this was just an example since you had PHP in  your tags.